# installing SQL Server Express 2008 on 2005

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, bootstrapper

I have an instance with a certain name in SQL Server Express 2005, and I want to install SQL Server Express 2008, and having the SAME INSTANCE NAME, since the old app version I'm trying to installer comes with a SQL Server Express 2005 installer, and the new one with SQL Server Express 2008 installer.

I don't want users to uninstall the old application (and thus the SQL Server Express 2005 instance), so would it be possible to have something like and "upgrade" of the instance?

I'm using a bootstrapper with the following line:

```
<Command PackageFile="SQLEXPR32_x86_ENU.EXE"
         Arguments='/q /hideconsole /action=Upgrade /features=SQL /instancename=DUBOCALC 
                   /enableranu=1 /sqlsvcaccount="NT Authority\Network Service" 
                   /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="Builtin\Users" /skiprules=RebootRequiredCheck'
         EstimatedInstalledBytes="225000000"
         EstimatedInstallSeconds="420">
```

Thanks a lot everybody in advance!

Comment: I would suggest removing the SQL Express 2005 it will not hurt anything I had the same issue last week with sql server 2008 R2 the enterprise manager would not install / show up... I removed 2005 and wah-la everything worked perfect... remove 2005 it's old and useless.. in my opinion

Comment: yes, but it have some consequences on the old version for the users? in the instance it's probably stored all the changes in the DB they made..

Comment: Just google for sql 2005 to 2008 upgrade wizard. Or back up user dbs, remove, install and restore.

Comment: I would follow gbn suggestion.. I totally forgot about the different port that each instance utilizes.. good catch there GBN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have the same Instance name or use the same port. Each instance must be unique in these regards.

You have to do an "in-situ" upgrade

Comment: how do I do an in-situ upgrade?

Comment: @noloman: honestly, don't know. Never done one. I don't use Express and always migrate servers... will be something on MSDN